# Datepicker sin sábado/domingo, sin feriados, a partir de determinado día

Tags: datepicker, jquery-ui

Buen día, revisando varios tutoriales y acá mismo no pude dar con un ejemplo que se adapte a lo que necesito. Logré que funcionaran independientemente (feriados, sin fines de semana o a partir de una fecha), pero no las 3 cosas a la vez. Puntualmente no logro que me deshabilite los *datesDisabled* (17/8/2020).

Mi código:

```
$(function() {
   $('#fecha').datepicker({ 
        //disableWeekends: true                 // no funciono    
        beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends // weekends no habilitados
        ,minDate: 15                           // a partir de 15 dias se puede seleccionar
      
        ,format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
        datesDisabled: ['2020-8-17', '2020-08-17']
   });
   
   
   
});
```

Comment: Disculpa mi ignorancia, que lenguaje estas utilizando?

Comment: uso javascript dentro de un php

Answer (score 1):

```
var unavailableDates = ["17-8-2020","12-10-2020","23-11-2020","7-12-2020","8-12-2020","25-12-2020"];

function unavailable(date) {
        dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth()+1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
        if ($.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) < 0) {
        return $.datepicker.noWeekends (date) // weekends no habilitados
        } else {
        return [false,"","Booked Out"];
        }
        }
 $(function() {
       $('#fecha).datepicker({ 
                                beforeShowDay: 
                                unavailable,        // aplico la funcion de feriados ,
                                minDate: 15        // a partir de 15dias seleccionable
                             });
                               
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer un array con las fechas que quieres deshabilitar para añadirlas a `noWeekends` y de esa forma deshabilitarlas, luego con `minDate: 15` restringes las fechas a 15 dias atras, igual se me ocurre que para "automatizarlo" podrías guardar los feriados en una DB enviarle las fechas a JS desde PHP por ejemplo. Y aunque no la he utilizado, también existe [esta libreria](https://github.com/commenthol/date-holidays) que obtiene las fechas de los días feriados de algunos países, quizá podrías implementarla en tu proyecto y así evitar la parte de obtener y/o colocar las fechas manualmente. Ojala te sirva. Saludos.

```js
var QuitarFechas = ["6/8/2020","17/8/2020","02/11/2020","25/12/2020","31/12/2020"];
        
function deshabilitar(date) {
hoy = date.getDate() + "/" + (date.getMonth()+1) + "/" + date.getFullYear();
if ($.inArray(hoy, QuitarFechas) < 0) {return $.datepicker.noWeekends (date)} 
else {return [false,"","Fecha deshabilitada"];}
}
 $(function() {
$('#datepicker').datepicker({ 
        minDate: 15,
        beforeShowDay: deshabilitar
       });                         
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css"/>
<input id="datepicker">
```